# DownloadButton width in R Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm having problems to change my DownloadButton width, since he's different from actionButton (which have the width parameter).

Any easy ideas to solve it?
Here's my code (Just a simple download button):

````
Normalidade  
=======================================================================
Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
<h5>
```{r}
tags$hr()


downloadButton("downloadNormal",label = "Download seu teste", class = "butt1")


downloadHandler(
    filename = "Resultados_Normal.csv",

    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data, file)
    }

    )

tags$hr()
tags$br()
actionButton("AjudaNormal", label = " Ajuda", icon("question-circle"),
             width = "100%",
             onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')")


```
</h5>
````

Comment: You can apply custom css using the `style` argument, like: `downloadButton("id", "Label", style = "width:300px;")`

Comment: Didnt work, nothing happened. Any other ideas?
The same for the label parameter, doesnt matter which name I put in there, the button always shows "Download" for the user. Maybe because I'm using flexdashboard?

Comment: You're right it's not working on Flexdashboard indeed. Try adding the following css rule: `.shiny-download-link {width: 100%;}`. Info about adding CSS if needed: [link](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#css_styles)

Comment: I'm new to this, so don't be angry hahaha. But I didn't get how I should put this rule, like:
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
 css: style.shiny-download-link {width: 100%;}

Comment: There is no problem with being new to things :) I wrote up an answer, test it and let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, after playing around with this I recommend to use `uiOutput` with `renderUI`.

Without using `uiOutput` the `downloadButton` function gets ignored (only the `downloadHandler` gets evaluated), that's why the `width` parameter was not set, and also you can't modify the label of the button.

There are all solved with using `uiOutput`.

````
---
title: "Full width downloadButton"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
# Create placeholder for the downloadButton
uiOutput("downloadUI")
```

```{r}
# Create the actual downloadButton
output$downloadUI <- renderUI( {
  downloadButton("downBtn", "Download Iris data", style = "width:100%;")
})

# Add download handling
output$downBtn <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    "iris.csv"
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(iris, file, row.names = FALSE)
  }
)
```
````

I set the `width` using **inlineCSS** with the `style` argument, but you can (and should) use an external style sheet if you have multiple CSS rules.

#### Using an external stylesheet (CSS file)

An external CSS file can be used in Flexdashboard by adding `css: path/filename.css` to the YAML header.

```
---
title: "Full width downloadButton"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
runtime: shiny
---
```

In this case the app tries to read a file called `styles.css` in the same folder as the `Rmd`.

Create the css file in the same folder and add the rule:

```
#downBtn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can now remove `style = "width:100%;"` from the `downloadButton` and still get full width button.

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: WORKED! You're my angel hahaha. I figured out how to add a class too, because I'll have tons of download buttons and would be boring to add the ID style for everyone. Really helped!

Comment: This is the only way I could get a `downloadButton` to **work** with `runtime: shiny_prerendered`